# Old duplicate, poor problem description and no helpful answers

Tags: discussion

I wanted to ask a question on how to import colors (materials) from .stp files. A query brought up a similar question with answers ([Want to import an STP file to blender with colors](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/51790/want-to-import-an-stp-file-to-blender-with-colors)), that contains virtually no information. The question doesn't cover the topic well inmho, and maybe this is why there are so few answers.

The question also is over 1,5 years old. So: is it okay to post a new question? Knowing that it is definitely a duplicate?

When I would edit the question, in order to cover the topic, I'd rewrite the whole thing -- that doesn't sound right.

As this is a primarily opinion based matter, I'd suggest to drop your thoughts in a one-line answer and vote for one another, after a few days I'll select the answer with most upvotes.

thanks & bye,
yann

Comment: I'd recommend that at any point you find an old post that matches the criteria you described and you are positive that your update is an improvement then go for a new post **while linking to the old one**.

Explain what you found lacking and detail your post around its shortcomings. It doesn't hurt to refresh an old topic and possibly bring more attention or attract better answers. It could possibly be marked a duplicate of yours in due turn.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Thanks for asking on meta :)

I'd say yes, it is definitely fine to post a new question.

The main purpose of closing duplicates to redirect information on one topic to one place, but if the information in the one place is stale and no longer suffices to answer the question, this means new information is needed. It makes sense to keep this separate from the old information (but linked).

I would link the old question in your new question and give your reasons for asking it anew to prevent hasty close votes and getting the same answers as the old question.